# What is the German word for paper abortion?

Tags: translation, word-choice

‚[Paper abortion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_abortion)‘, auf dänisch ‚[juridisk abort](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juridisk_abort)‘, ist eine stark umstrittene Thematik. Es gibt zwar einen [englischen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_abortion) und einen [dänischen Wikipediaartikel](https://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juridisk_abort) zum Thema, jedoch keinen deutschen Beitrag.

Ich würde vielleicht gerne etwas darüber schreiben, weil ich ein paar Abhandlungen zu dieser Thematik gelesen habe. Jedoch kenne ich kein deutsches Wort für *paper abortion*.

Es geht dabei nicht um einen tatsächlichen Schwangerschaftsabbruch, bei dem das ungeborene Kind stirbt, sondern um eine Forderung aus der Männer(rechts)bewegung, dem werdenden biologischen Vater das zeitlich beschränkte, unwiderrufliche Recht einzuräumen jeglichen Rechten und Pflichten zu entsagen, die sich normalerweise aus einer (auch nicht formell anerkannten) Vaterschaft ergeben; dazu kann auch gehören, dem Kind das Recht auf Kenntnis seiner Abstammung väterlicherseits zu entziehen.

Könnt ihr mir vielleicht helfen ein deutsches Wort zu finden oder gar zu erstellen? Am liebsten mehrere Wörter, wenn möglich.

Comment: Ich schätze dafür muss erst ein Wort erfunden werden. Wie wäre es mit Vaterschaftsablehnung?

Comment: Auf Wikipedia gelten Wortschöpfungen als [Theoriefindung](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Keine_Theoriefindung) (_original research_) und werden nicht gerne gesehen. Sollte sich in der deutschen Öffentlichkeit noch keine Bezeichnung etabliert haben, etwa weil der Diskurs gar nicht stattfindet, gäbe es wahrscheinlich auch keinen Grund für einen Artikel, außer wenn sich dieser auf die Diskussion in anderen Ländern bezieht – dann könnte der lokale Begriff verwendet werden, sofern es einen neutralen gibt.

Comment: Ich vermute jemand hat sich von dieser Diskussion inspirieren lassen. Jetzt gibt es einen deutschen Artikel (auch wenn seine Löschung vorgeschlagen wurde): https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formale_Gleichstellung_zu_dem_weiblichen_Schwangerschaftsabbruch

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass die anwesenden Akademiker auch schon *Paper Abortions* vorgenommen haben.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Im deutschsprachigen Internet wird das Konzept offenbar unter dem Begriff ["juristische Abtreibung"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22juristische%20abtreibung%22), vereinzelt auch ["formale Abtreibung"](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22formale%20Abtreibung%22), diskutiert.

Das scheint mir eine durchaus passende *Übersetzung* zu sein, denn auch die genannten englischen und dänischen Begriffe versuchen offenbar, eine Analogie zur Abtreibung herzustellen. Dabei wird jedoch auf die rechtlichen Implikationen der Vaterschaft fokussiert. Ob es eine gute Idee ist, beides in einem Begriff zusammenzubringen, ist eine andere Frage, die den Schöpfern der dänischen bzw. englischen Versionen gestellt werden muss. Eine Frau kann nicht nur "juristisch" bzw. "on paper" abtreiben.

Comment: Persönliche Anmerkung: die "Contra"-Argumente in dem englischen WP-Artikel erscheinen mir arg kurz geraten.

Comment: "in einer Weise zu beenden, wie es ansonsten durch eine *Abtreibung* geschehen würde" - also so, dass das Kind nachher nicht existiert? Ich halte den Begriff für vollkommen unpassend weil irreführend. Intuitiv würde ich eine "juristische Abtreibung" als mit juristischen Mitteln erzwungene Abtreibung bei der werdenden Mutter verstehen, aber vielleicht ist das auch nur mein persönlicher Eindruck.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich denke, dass der Begriff unpassend erscheint, weil die Idee, die er ausdrücken soll, zweifelhafte Analogien zieht. Jemand, der von der Idee noch nie gehört hat, wird sie sich aus dem Begriff nicht herleiten können - aber das gilt mMn genauso für _paper abortion_ und vermutlich (ich kann kein Dänisch, aber auch da scheint _Abtreibung_ das Hauptwort zu sein) für _juridisk abort_. Da nach einer Übersetzung gefragt war, war es nicht mein Ziel, die inhärenten Schwächen des Originalbegriffs zu kaschieren oder auszumerzen.

Comment: Entsprechende Stichwörter aus der Politolinguistik sind u.a. _Begriffe prägen, Fahnenwort, Kampfbegriff_ und natürlich _Euphemismus_, siehe auch [Neusprech](http://neusprech.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Unabhängig vom verwendeten Attribut ist *Abtreibung* (aber auch *abort[ion]*) ein unpassender Ausdruck für das Konzept, den lediglich verwenden kann, wer zwecks Legitimierung eine Analogie zur feministisch geprägten Abtreibungsrechtsdebatte herstellen möchte. Das gleiche gilt für *Schwangerschaftsabbruch*, aus dem man ***Vaterschaftsabbruch*** herleiten könnte, oder das euphemistische *Schwangerschaftsunterbrechung*.

Natürlich geht mit einer Abtreibung auch die Mutterschaft (sowie Vaterschaft) zuende bevor sie richtig begonnen hat, aber stets auf Kosten des Lebens des ungeborenen Kindes. Letzteres ist bei der ***Ablehnung* der Vaterschaft** nicht der Fall. Rechtlich gäbe es noch ein paar andere einschlägige Begriffe, die evtl. verwendet werden könnten, bspw. ***Niederlegung*** (auch nach Geburt) oder ***Abtretung*** (impliziert einen Empfänger). Sie alle setzen eine Anerkennung oder zumindest ein prinzipielles Eingeständnis der biologischen Vaterschaft voraus, also sind *Abstreitung* oder *Anfechtung* keine passenden Begriffe. *Verzicht* und *Auschluss* der Vaterschaftsanerkennung wie von @Awita vorgeschlagen könnten hingegen funktionieren, wobei ersteres klingt, als sei es gerichtlich überstimmbar.

Das passendere Analogon wäre übrigens die [anonyme Geburt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonyme_Geburt) (u.a. „Babyklappe“) bzw. anonyme Samenspende, also ***anonyme* Vaterschaft** (bzw. Elternschaft). 
Ein annäherndes Antonym wäre die Adoption, wo i.d.R. ein nicht leibliches Kind freiwillig (*optio*) als rechtlich gleichgestelltes eigenes Kind angenommen (*ad*) wird, denn beim diskutierten Konzept wird jede rechtliche Verbindung zum leiblichen Kind gekappt, daher vielleicht ****Desoption, *Aboption, *Exoption*** o.ä.

Comment: *Wenn* man wirklich die offenbar beabsichtigte Parallele zum Begriff in der Frauenrechtsbewegung nachvollziehen will, dann ist "Vaterschaftsabbruch" eindeutig die beste Lösung.

Comment: @KilianFoth Ja, *wenn*. Das Wort ist mir erst nachträglich eingefallen und hat bisher 0 Googletreffer. _Mutterschaftsabbruch_ wäre dann entweder ein anderes Wort für anonyme Geburt oder ein Euphemismus für Schwangerschaftsabbruch; analog _Elternschaftsabbruch_.

Answer (score 1):

Vaterschaftsabtretung

Vaterschaftsanfechtung

Abtretungserklärung

These are all the possible words I can think of.

Comment: "Abtretung" ist in diesem Kontext ein Euphemismus.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube nicht, dass es dafür einen deutschen Begriff gibt. Man müsste es wohl mit *"Verzicht auf Anerkennung der Vaterschaft"*, *"Ausschluss der Vaterschaftsanerkennung"* oder *"formale Gleichstellung zu einer Abtreibung"* umschreiben.

Wenn es nicht ganz genau sein muss, aber etwas griffiger sein soll, könnte man vielleicht auch *"formale Abtreibung"* benutzen.

Answer (score 1):

Für mich klingt der beschriebene Prozess nach "ich will plötzlich (de jure) nur ein Samenspender und (de jure) kein Vater sein".

In Deutschland gilt seit [2018 (di-netz.de)](http://di-netz.de/bundestag-beschliest-samenspenderregistergesetz-gesetzgebung-teil-18/) das [Samenspende-Register-Gesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/saregg/index.html), womit eine Auskunft zum Samenspender möglich ist, ohne dass dabei Unterhaltsansprüche etc. entstehen. Siehe [§ 4 Nr. 6 SaRegG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/saregg/__4.html) in Verbindung mit [§ 1600d Satz 4 BGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bgb/__1600d.html).  Eintrag zur künstlichen Befruchtung im [Wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%BCnstliche_Befruchtung#Besonderheiten_in_Deutschland) mit Verweis auf diese Quellen.

Es müsste für das gesuchte Pendant de jure möglich sein, den "One-Night-Stand" als die Prozedur in einer Samenspende-Klinik zu definieren und das dem Sex vorausgehende Einverständis in die dort nötige klinische Aufklärung umzuwandeln.

Die Mutter wird im Zweifel nach § 1600d S. 1 BGB im Falle eines solchen "ich will nicht" die Vaterschaft gerichtlich feststellen lassen (müssen). Daher gehe ich davon aus, dass der deutsche Gesetzgeber auch sonst alle Wege ausschöpft, um einen Vater zu bestimmen. Denn [§ 6 Satz 2 GG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/gg/art_6.html) sagt ganz klar, dass Pflege und Erziehung zuallererst Sache der Eltern ist - wozu Eltern ermittelt werden müssen. (Die ersten 20 § im GG sind nur sehr schwer zu ändern!)

Mangels rechtlicher Möglichkeiten gehe ich daher davon aus, dass es diesen Begriff de jure nicht geben kann.

Answer (score 0):

Es handelt sich hier um  die Forderung, einen juristischen Akt zu ermöglichen, mit dem der biologische Vater auf alle Rechte verzichtet und alle Pflichten verweigert.

Wie wäre es mit "Vaterschaftsablehnung" oder "Vaterschaftsverweigerung"? Das trifft zugegebenermaßen nicht den Verzichtsaspekt. Alternative: "Vaterschaftsannulierung".